# How to Disable the button tap in 5 seconds by using rxSwift?

Tags: rx-swift

**rxSwift version:**

pod 'RxSwift', '6.2.0'
pod 'RxCocoa', '6.2.0'

```
TrueBtn.rx.tap.throttle(.seconds(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in

print("TrueBtn-true")

}).disposed(by: bag)
```

How to Disable the button tap in 5 seconds by using `rxSwift`?

There is a false button in the same view.

```
FalseBtn.rx.tap.throttle(.seconds(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in

print("FalseBtn-false")

}).disposed(by: bag)
```

I click the true button and after 1 second click the true button again. Then I click the false button.
Now the result is :

> TrueBtn-true
> wait for 1 second
> FalseBtn-false
> wait 4 seconds
> TrueBtn-true

I want this:

> TrueBtn-true
> wait for 1 second
> FalseBtn-false
> wait more than 5 seconds
> print nothing

`parameter latest: Should latest element received in a due time wide time window since last element emission is emitted.`

Can I write some code to set the latest
value to false without changing the `rx-swift` api?

Comment: What is printing "print nothing"? If you mean that it doesn't print anything, then why "wait more than 5 seconds"?

Comment: @DanielT.  I mean it doesn't print anything.  I want to show all readers that I wait for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case is a bit confusing to me. I'm going to assume it's something like.

> When the user taps either the true or false button, they have 5 seconds to change their mind and tap the other button. Once the grace period is up, the app will print their choice and disable further taps.

Some marble diagrams to demonstrate:
User makes a selection and doesn't change their mind.

```
true:   --T-----
false:  --------
result: -------T|
```

User makes a selection and changes their mind before the 5 seconds are up.

```
true:   --T---------
false:  ------F-----
result: -----------F|
```

User makes a selection and tries to change their mind after 5 seconds.

```
true:   --T-----------
false:  --------F-----
result: -------T|
```

Here is the code that will do the above:

```
func useCase(trueButton: Observable<Void>, falseButton: Observable<Void>, scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<Bool> {
    Observable.merge(
        trueButton.map { true },
        falseButton.map { false }
    )
    .debounce(.seconds(5), scheduler: scheduler)
    .take(1)
}
```

Comment: I change`throttle(.seconds(5), scheduler`  to `throttle(.seconds(5), lastest: false,scheduler`  .My code work for me.

Comment: How to set the default `lastest` value to false? The value of `rx-Swift` api is true.

Comment: There is no default in the code I posted above. If you want it to emit `false` before the user taps any button, then just put `.startWith(false)` under the `.take(1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will improve my English and make a better description for the user on this site.